# jQuery ui Datepicker format of picker itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I already searched a bit now but found nothing so far. I try to find a special date format not for the output/hidden field or whatever but for the datepicker itself. Default the datepicker shows years, months, days and there are a handful of options for that.

**Now my question:** Are there any options of setting a dateformat for the days rows/cols ? Default only the number of the day is displayed. I need something like this:

```
Mo  | Tu  | We  | .....
01  | 02  | 03  | .....
May | May | May | .....
_________________
Mo  | Tu  | We  | .....
08  | 09  | 10  | .....
May | May | May | .....
_________________
::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: Is this the datepicker structure or value structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use this version of jQuery Datapicker with the onDate event: http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#daymods

Comment: yep. tried many things. before i start to hack around in datepicker core, i will try it. I started now to use it and its a really mighty thing and easy to use with many options. looking forward :)